# Using MVC, How can I pass an anchor tag on a form submit?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

In short, I'm trying to hit an anchor on the page I am submitting to.

So my code looks like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Times#" + Model.SelectedTimeSort, "Patron", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmBuildings" }))
```

but on the form it comes out as:

```
<form action="/Times%23Evening" id="frmBuildings" method="post">
```

How do I set this up to submit and pass an anchor tag?

Comment: Anchor tags don't get passed through to the server, so there would be little point in this.

Comment: I'm not trying to pass it to the server, just have it in the URL (edit- I'm just trying to pass it like one would use it in a traditional <a href="/Times#Evening">).  I'll be honest, I feel silly but I just have never used anchor tags, so I have no idea how they work.  If I access the site via    http://localhost/Times#Evening then I get the result I want.  This is what I'm trying to convey in my form submission.

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `Html.BeginForm` at all, or any HTML Helper that will encode that URL. Try outputting the full form element using `Html.Raw` (and don't forget the closing element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are posting to another MVC method on your application:

You would need to add some JavaScript to the page, then in your ViewModel add an Anchor string property which is set in the MVC controller postback code, when the view loads the javascript (onLoad) can detect the parameter and scroll the page to the anchor:

```
location.hash = "#" + "@(Model.MyAnchorName)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the Html.BeginForm and use an html **form** tag with a Url.Action

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Times", "Patron")#@Model.SelectedTimeSort" id="frmBuildings" method="post">
</form>
```

Relying on javascript per the correct answer seems like overkill just to keep the "BeginForm" around.